# String override in whole project using .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a string "**this is fun**".  i want to change to "**JUST fun**".
Can we change using .htaccess file. I have written this rule

```
RewriteRule ^this is fun  JUST fun
```

But nothing happens. I can't change the each file as its huge project and deployed on server already.

Can we do this using .htaccess only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. `.htaccess` is for Apache web server configuration, not for performing string replacements in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You can change it on PHP script itself. if you have similar strings in more than one places. then keep it as a variable in config file or the file which includes on those pages and then use that variable. I don't think the way via htaccess